# dynamic generate jplayer playlist with json response

Tags: jquery, json, jplayer, playlist

**jplayer is not working when I get the data from cookie** But If I assigned value manually to variable it's working fine. So I am not getting what is the problem, Please help me out If anyone face the same problem.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  var getMusic = $.cookie('getCMusic'); // console.log(getMusic) is showing data but not adding in jplayer playlist
  // I added manually in variable it is working fine data sample geeting by cookie //[{"music_id":71,"title":"music nfs 2 title","artist":"music nfs 2 artist","poster":"http://localhost/bespoke/public/image/422a9411a2e8e21c499d8686574d03d29f4118ae9554825.jpg","mp3":"http://localhost/bespoke/public/preview_music/d90414085090c355793b1c2e5faba4f0cb84c1195108785.mp3"}];
    new jPlayerPlaylist({
      jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_1",
      cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_1"
    },getMusic, {
      swfPath: "../../dist/jplayer",
      supplied: "webmv, ogv, m4v, oga, mp3",
      useStateClassSkin: true,
      autoBlur: false,
      smoothPlayBar: true,
      keyEnabled: true,
      audioFullScreen: true
    });
});
```

Comment: please copy and paste here the data of cookie from console, and also show what are you adding manually.

Comment: I already mention in second comment line

Comment: Are you sure the var `getMusic` has the data `[{"music_id":71,"title":"music nfs 2 title","artist":"music nfs 2 artist","poster":"http://localhost/bespoke/public/image/422a9411a2e8e21c499d8686574d03d29f4118ae9554825.jpg","mp3":"http://localhost/bespoke/public/preview_music/d90414085090c355793b1c2e5faba4f0cb84c1195108785.mp3"}];`?

Comment: yes, I am sure @MartinMazzaDawson

Comment: Post jsfiddle please